# Restrict GitLab pipeline/job based on whether the source is a merge commit

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am specifically **not** talking about *merge **requests***, which I know I can restrict jobs for with with `only:` or `except:` statements, and which have ample questions on the site already. I want to restrict certain jobs (expensive testing) from running for *merge **commits*** - for a merge request to be merged, unit testing must pass, so it makes no sense to run unit tests again right after merging.

But the only answer I found to that requirement was to restrict tests from ever running on the `master` branch completely, and we still want to be able to run tests there, we just don't want the tests to run if the commit was a merge commit coming from a merge request where the tests already ran (we only allow merging if tests pass). So simply restricting tests from running on the `master` branch is not a good solution for us.

I also found multiple references to `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` containing `"merge_request_event"` if the pipeline was triggered by merging a merge request, but that doesn't seem to be the case in current GitLab instances. Instead, the variable contains `"push"`, which seems like a bug or at least a misnomer, considering no pushes are involved when I click *Merge now* on a merge request.

So I am looking for a `.gitlab-ci.yml` declaration which will prevent a job from running if the pipeline was triggered by a merge commit, but still allow it to run if a pipeline is created on the same branch for any other reason than a merge commit.

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, looking for `merge_request_event` in `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` won't help you here because you're looking to change the pipeline behavior for the pipeline that results *after* the merge. By the time an MR is merged, the MR is closed and there are no more pipelines caused by merge request events.

Because merge commits are no different from any other kind of commit pushed to the branch, the best way to do this would be to rely on the commit message. When you merge an MR in GitLab, it will have a default uniform message (unless a user edits the merge commit message manually) that will be in the form `Merge branch '<source_branch_name>' into '<taget_branch_name>'`.

```
my_job:
  rules: # skip merge commits
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^Merge branch/
      # you could make this regex pattern more specific if you wish
      when: never
    - when: on_success
```